# select json b field of array postgresql of an array field in json

Tags: postgresql, query

*Postgresql version:
PostgreSQL 13.5

```
alter table accounts
    add tags jsonb default '[]'::jsonb not null;

 select DISTINCT AC.tags
     from accounts as AC where account_type = 'TEAM';
```

[image]

this query is returning me this result:

```
[
   {
      "tags":[
         "adiputra6/frontend"
      ]
   },
   {
      "tags":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "tags":[
         "data extraction",
         ".net",
         "nlp"
      ]
   },
   {
      "tags":[
         "bootstrap",
         "ecommerce",
         "mysql",
         "paypal",
         "shopping cart"
      ]
   },
   {
      "tags":[
         "launcher"
      ]
   },
   
]
```

(I am using distinct cause it can have duplicate values inside the json tags, and i need a list without duplicates values)

i have tried the jsonb '->' operator:

```
select DISTINCT AC.tags->'tags'
 from accounts as AC where account_type = 'TEAM';
```

result from the previous query:  [{"?column?":null}]

i would like to get a result of distinct list in a single line like:

tags:   {"launcher",  "bootstrap","ecommerce","mysql", "paypal","shopping cart"...}

how can i do that ?

found a solution in here but it dosen t work in my case and i can t understand why data looks the same:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dc11527694d1f7bc642464f6100f49ad

Comment: Please *always* start by declaring your Postgres version and table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement). And explain the purpose of `DISTINCT` in your query. It rarely makes sense to apply it to a JSON value. Finally: your query would return a *set*, but you display a single JSON value. Please clarify.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for your returns, i have edit the post.

Comment: Still, the displayed result is a ***single*** JSON value, while the query would return a set of values. Is there some undeclared middleware merging the set into a JSON array? Some sample rows for the source table would be instrumental, ideally in a fiddle. Random example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=66ef3c1777db02fdbf48ba7c822a8542

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you again for your help, i have added an image to the post of field tags in account table, he is not as you have concept it in the example, pleas check.

Comment: Please post sample data as *text*, never as image.

Comment: excuse my english, why its not good in image ?

Comment: We cannot copy/paste data from an image. Ideally, provide a fiddle to work with. I could have answered your question in a minute if you had done that.

Comment: okey got you, my bad.

Comment: The fiddle contradicts your image. Please present a consistent question..

Comment: Why it contradicts the image?

Comment: Because the image has separate rows for each `tags` array, but the fiddle has it all in one big blob. This is exactly what @ErwinBrandstetter [said to you before](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310188/select-json-b-field-of-array-postgresql-of-an-array-field-in-json#comment604108_310188)

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what your image shows, your fiddle has a *single* JSON blob, containing an array of objects, each with a `tags` array.

It appears you want to pull out all of these arrays, combine them into a single array, and put it into a single object with the value `tags`.

```
SELECT json_build_object('tags', jsonb_agg(DISTINCT tag.value))
FROM accounts as a
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(a.tags) AS tagsArray(value)
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements_text(tagsArray.value->'tags') AS tag(value);
```

| Result |
| --- |
| {"tags" : ["3d printing", "adiputra6/frontend", "api", "automated testing", "bioinformatics", "c#", "c++", "callerid", "cdp", "chat", "cnam", "company", "customer data platform", "data", "data append", "dev ops", "game development", "games", "gmail", "googlechrome", "gpg", "gpg gmail chrome chromium", "haskell", "html5", "ios", "irc", "java", "maker", "metabolomics", "monitoring", "ndk", "nitrux", "notes", "open-source", "package manager", "phone", "phone data", "robotics", "roguelike", "ros", "ruby", "science", "syntax checking", "telephony", "vala", "wayland", "web game", "workflow"]} |

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1a7d686ecb03964a7000d416d342a875)

There are a several levels here:

- Shred the main array of each row of `accounts` into individual rows of objects.
- Of each of those objects, shred the `tags` property also.
- Aggregate distinct tag values as a JSON array.
- Build a JSON object of that as the property `tags`.

---

Assuming that what you *actually* have is many rows, each with a single JSON array of tag strings (like the image), you can use the following simpler solution instead:

```sql
SELECT json_build_object('tags', jsonb_agg(DISTINCT tag.value))
FROM accounts as a
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(a.tags) AS tag(value);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1559912c587effc60680444e255515f0)

Comment: thank you for you response, but im still not getting nothing  in my real world example, im getting  {"tags" : null} and i don t know why

Comment: You are going to have to show your "real world example" because I used your fiddle. If your data or expected results are different then please show that in a new fiddle

Comment: acutally i think that im showing the real data in fiddl but clearly and as u sayd the problem is there how can i be sure to show the real data in fiddl ? based on the image of data what do you think is missing ?

Comment: Your image shows individual rows each having a JSON array of strings, `["c#","game engine","games"]` `[]` `[]` etc. Your fiddle shows something completely different: a *single* row of one giant JSON blob, containing an array of objects each with a `tags` property containing an array `[{"tags":["adiputra6/frontend"]}, {"tags":[]}, ..... ]` So what do you *actually* have?

Comment: what i really have is ["c#","game engine","games"] [] [] ... but i think that im badly putting it in the fiddl, how can i fix that in fiddl ? cause i am really not seen the difference... when i insert

Comment: OK I have added another solution for that

Comment: thank you so much this works